Why did a moderator close this Identify-This-film question?
This identification question (Italian B&W movie from the fifties) was asked a few days ago. It contains a considerable amount of detail about a charming-sounding film set in Italy in the 1950s and featuring a man whose father visits him in Rome for the day,  but becomes disillusioned of big-city life.
Despite being well-written and containing a wealth of useful detail it subsequently attracted a close vote for "needing more detail" and then, surprisingly, was closed by a moderator. I'm at a loss why this would be the case when identify-this-x questions are on-topic again.
Why has it been closed?

This closure is pretty odd, especially since it was closed after the question already had an answer and was featured in the Hot Network Questions list. It's unlikely the community would have closed it, so the moderator's intervention is surprising. I doubt it would get 5 non-mod votes to close it. It would be great if the moderator could explain why they closed it, considering the OP gave several details about the movie.

Update: After the same moderator "left closed" in review, the community reopened the question.

This seems to happen occasionally. I have the feeling most ID questions are still looked at with overzealous suspicion, and even the more fleshed out ID questions tend to receive at least a few downvotes. I'm guessing the answer is something unsatisfying like "because some users (including moderators) don't like the community's stance on ID questions".

@Joachim - This seems to be a pattern of unilateral decision-making rather than a single isolated error, though.

I can imagine it got closed for lack of details, but then the question is: why haven't many other, less informative questions been closed? That suggests this decision wasn't made completely objectively in the first place, and some elaboration on the decision would be appreciated (although I agree with Rand al'Thor and wouldn't hold the reasoning against anyone). If it is simply still the disagreement with ID-q's (whereby they're held to a higher standard), that's something that needs addressing.

(@galacticninja HNQs are no metric for quality, though. Nor is the presence of answers, actually.)

@Joachim You're right, HNQs don't always reflect quality, and I didn't mean to suggest otherwise. It's just a bit unfortunate because being on the HNQ list brings more traffic and engagement to our site from the wider SE community. Closing the question took it off the HNQ, which means we lost that opportunity.

@Joachim "because some users don't like the community's stance on ID questions" - You tellin' me there's people you disagree with the community consensus? And they're hiding within that community? Next you're telling me they even happen to be part of the community. That would be a rather dissatisfying fact indeed, if even a fact of life itself. ;-)

@NapoleonWilson - It's not so much that they dislike ID questions, it's that they dislike the kind of people who ask ID questions, referring to them as stains and pests.

@Valorum Oh, I see. So they just hate people? What a despicable bunch indeed. I don't think there's a need to drag this through the mud like that, Valorum. And as always, if you see someone genuinely insulting a user rather than disliking their question, flag that comment. You know how the site works by now. Anything beyond that isn't any less of a broad-stroked denigration of an entire group than the one you claim to happen.

@NapoleonWilson - What I'm seeing is people systematically downvoting every ID question and abusing the close vote system in order to try to make users feel unwelcome. And it's working.

And now we've gone from claims of insults to vague interpretaitons of the closing and voting mechanisms as insults. That is the questionable "close votes are bad for site engagement" (which isn't even wrong as a fact) philosophy from SE corporate all the way again. At the end of the day, noone likes their question close-voted, literally noone with absolutely no question. Yet extrapolation of intent out of this is entirely your own interpretation again, Richard. And in fact I don't actually observe that...

...In fact most of the questions seem to be surprisingly well upvoted and I can't even say I don't understand this because I admit that many of the ID questions we got so far aren't entirely terrible. I personally found myself not having to downvote a lot of them finding they look "okay for an ID question". It's not the worst start for this "brave new world", to quote Rand. ;-)...

...Of course there's a few downvotes here and there, some of the questions genuinely suck and maybe some users downvote all of them because they don't like the questions at all or they have stricter quality guidelines than others. But honestly, what on god's green earth did you expect to happen after this meta discussion full of upvotes and downvotes and various opinions? Everyone suddenly loves these questions? You're not stupid Richard. You know as good as anyone else that consensus isn't a magic brainwash. We wouldn't be here otherwise. ;-)...

...The questions are back and I have to admit they're doing suprisingly well...so far. They're not amazing but we all know they could be so much worse. I think we can celebrate that and start to move on from denigrating an entire leigitmate part of the community or construing malicious intent out of thin air. Let's please stop the gaslighting and rather concentrate on dealing with the actual questions.

@NapoleonWilson It was mostly an observation, because there is a clear tendency to downvote this type of question (which indeed is democracy at work, but not an indication of quality, which is what voting is for), and when one that is not particularly light on details gets closed for lacking them, it's ..remarkable :)

The moderator in question did leave a comment on the post:

The insights are given in the first comment. It does not become a good question automatically just because you think you got the answer.

Where "the first comment" is a link to this meta answer. In lieu of further commentary from the moderator himself, we can pretty much understand that he felt the question is not up to the standards outlined in that meta post and therefore should be closed as being not detailed enough. He wasn't the only close-voter; the first one was Paulie_D, who left that first comment and also wrote the linked meta answer. As we can see from the post timeline, the same moderator voted to Leave Closed in the review queue, thus removing the post from community review, but it was reopened by 5 community members anyway.
As a moderator on a couple of other SE sites, I can say that I'll use my close-hammer in cases that I think will be clear-cut and uncontroversial, where the question should obviously be closed and people aren't likely to object. I'm not always right, of course, and I'm happy to engage in discussions about my mod decisions if a significant chunk of the community disagrees. My guess is that AJ thought this case would be clear-cut and an uncontroversially close-worthy question, but it turned out not to be. Now the question has been through the whole process, let's not engage in a witch-hunt of the closing moderator - if the closure was incorrect, it's been reversed, and a correct answer has been posted and accepted, so no harm done. Going forward, a couple of ideas:

Should moderators refrain from hammering ID questions (perhaps only using their close-votes as a 4th or 5th vote) until we have more clear guidelines on which should be closed or reopened? I pose this as a question rather than a clear suggestion, because I'm not active enough here to be certain whether or not there are enough active close/reopen voters on the site for this to be viable. On some smaller SE sites, moderators need to be involved in closing/reopening, otherwise nothing will ever get done.

As a corollary to the above, if community members expect moderators to refrain until there are clear guidelines, then they should get on and create clear guidelines. Meta discussions are needed to establish which ID questions should be closed and which should be left open, in this brave new world where ID questions aren't totally disallowed any more.



This isn’t the first time the moderator has closed an ID question using their mod privilege. For instance, they recently closed another similar question. The meta post they referenced is meant to provide guidance on improving ID questions, not as a justification for closing them. It suggests several details that could make an ID question better, but it’s unrealistic to expect the OP to include all of them. It’s still unclear what specific requirements the moderator expects for the question to be reopened, which is why this discussion is happening.

Hopefully, the moderator can clarify their stance, especially if they plan to continue closing ID questions.

It’s been several days since this post went up, and there’s still no response from the moderator who closed the question, even though I’ve noticed them active on other posts (for example, they just closed another similar ID question). While I hope I’m wrong, it seems unlikely we’ll get a response from them at this point.
That said, I wanted to add my thoughts to the discussion.
The moderator’s decision to close the question feels quite puzzling, especially given the circumstances. The question had already received an answer and was featured on the Hot Network Questions list, which typically drives traffic and engagement to our site from the broader SE community. By closing it, though, the question was removed from the HNQ list, which seems counterproductive.
From what I’ve observed over the past few months, the community has established a fairly consistent approach to handling ID questions. These questions are usually only closed as "needs details or clarity" when the provided details are too vague to identify a single movie/show, or when the description is so broad it could match several different movies/shows. Most ID questions, however, remain open, which suggests the community isn’t overly strict about detail requirements. The decision to close this question under stricter criteria feels out of step with the community’s usual practices. It’s hard to imagine the community voting to close it on their own, which makes the moderator’s intervention all the more surprising.
One of the recurring criticisms of the previous ID question ban, as discussed in several meta posts, was that it seemed to be driven primarily by moderator influence rather than community consensus. Using moderator privileges to close ID questions now feels like a similar attempt to unilaterally enforce a policy or standard that the community hasn’t explicitly agreed upon. This approach echoes the concerns raised during the ID ban discussions, for example:

Why are ID questions banned when there are only 55 votes in favor of it and 135 votes against it?
What power structures are in place here? Is this site democratic?
We are discontinuing support for identification questions

From my experience across multiple SE sites, moderators typically only step in to close questions when it’s clear—and undisputed—that the community would support that action. With ID questions, however, opinions on what constitutes "enough detail" can vary widely from person to person. As such, I don’t believe it’s appropriate for moderators to use their privileges to close these ID questions. Instead, I’m asking the moderators to allow the community to decide which ID questions should be closed as "needs details or clarity."
If any moderator has a personal opinion on what details should be required for ID questions, they’re welcome to share it—just like any other user. The best way to do that would be by starting a meta discussion so the community can weigh in and reach a consensus.

Honestly (a) I didn't respond to this question because I was NOT the moderator in question and I cannot speak for them and (b) I support the judicious use of moderator close votes for clear cut situations.

@iandotkelly That makes sense. I was actually referring to the moderator who closed the question. I’ve updated my post to clarify.

@iandotkelly It’s worth noting that this isn’t the first time the moderator in question closed an ID question using their mod privilege. A similar question was closed recently, too. Both of those questions were reopened by the community, which suggests that this might not fit the description of a "judicious use of moderator close votes for clear cut situations."

@iandotkelly - The problem here is that it's 'pretty clear cut' that these questions shouldn't have been closed. They were almost immediately reopened by community vote and haven't attracted any more close votes.
